# Strip html from sqlite search on android

Tags: android, html, sqlite, search, trim

I have a data, let's say this is my data:

```
<div class=main>
<ol>

  <li>Vestibulum feugiat nisi dolor, et pharetra nisl tincidunt et. <span class=b1>Pellentesque</span> metus sem, condimentum quis massa nec, fringilla consectetur risus. </li>
  <li>Morbi eu nisi quis dui ultricies luctus eu facilisis diam. <span class=b1>Pellentesque</span> non orci lorem. Suspendisse elementum rhoncus nulla sit amet condimentum. </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

That data is stored in sqlite in table "ini" and column "Text".

And I have this search function:

```
public void search(View view) {

    String cari = searchText.getText().toString();

    if(cari.length() > 3){
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Text FROM ini WHERE Text LIKE ?", 
                    new String[]{"%" + cari + "%"});
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.search_list_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"Text"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.text});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        setListAdapter(null);
    }   
}
```

Let's say that I want to search "Pellentesque metus", which has `</span>` between two words (Pellentesque `</span>` metus). how to remove this `</span>`? or how to trim all html when the search query called?

Sorry for my english

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create additional column in your table and put stripped html

```
html.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", StringUtil.EMPTY)
```

Then you can use this column insteadof your real column.

Comment: is there no other way?

Comment: I use often this way in my project. I think it one of the best.

Answer (score 1):

The below common table expression query answers your question (and works for short html formatted strings), but is not recommended for production use.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  input(str) AS (
    VALUES('
      <div class=main>
      <ol>
        <li>Vestibulum feugiat nisi dolor, et pharetra nisl tincidunt et. <span class=b1>Pellentesque</span> metus sem, condimentum quis massa nec, fringilla consectetur risus. </li>
        <li>Morbi eu nisi quis dui ultricies luctus eu facilisis diam. <span class=b1>Pellentesque</span> non orci lorem. Suspendisse elementum rhoncus nulla sit amet condimentum. </li>
      </ol>
      </div>
    ')
  ),
  output(id, str) AS (
    SELECT 1, str
    FROM input
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id+1,
      trim(
        replace(str, 
          substr(str, instr(str, '<'), instr(str, '>') - instr(str, '<') + 1)
        , ''),
      x'200a')
    FROM output WHERE instr(str, '<') OR instr(str, '>')
  ),
  raw(html) AS (
    SELECT str FROM output ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
  )
SELECT html FROM raw WHERE html LIKE '%Pellentesque metus%';
```

Output:

```
Vestibulum feugiat nisi dolor, et pharetra nisl tincidunt et. Pellentesque metus sem, condimentum quis massa nec, fringilla consectetur risus. 
  Morbi eu nisi quis dui ultricies luctus eu facilisis diam. Pellentesque non orci lorem. Suspendisse elementum rhoncus nulla sit amet condimentum.
```

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.